# Prevent input type url default behavior using Flask

Tags: python, validation, flask, forms, wtforms

I have input type url in a form and Im trying to get the list of validation errors in the same page, but I want the form first send the data to the server and then render the error list but when the input type is set to url and I enter some other text It shows a popup and say Enter valid Url
It does it on the client side before sending any data to the server
I can use it with js and preventDefault but how can I overcome this default behavior using Flask

Here is my code

```
from flask_wtf import Form
from wtforms.fields import StringField
from flask.ext.wtf.html5 import URLField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired, url

class BookmarkForm(Form):
    url = URLField('url', validators = [DataRequired(), url()])
    description = StringField('description')
```

the main py file

```
@app.route('/add', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
def add():
    form = BookmarkForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        url = form.url.data
        description = form.description.data
        store_bookmark(url, description)
        flash('stored "{}"'.format(description))
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('add.html', form = form)
```

and the template

```
<form id='addUrl' action='' method='post' 
{% if form.url.errors %} class ='error'
{% endif %}>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <p>Please enter your bookmark here</p>
    {{ form.url(size = 50) }}
    <p>Please enter additional description</p>
    {{ form.description(size = 50) }}
    <ul>
         {% for error in form.url.errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
         {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the browser support of HTML5 and It causes client-side validation and prevents data to passed to the server. You can overcome that default behavior of the HTML5 URL field by adding the tag `novalidate` to your form.

Your template will look like this

```
<form id='addUrl' action='' method='post' novalidate
{% if form.url.errors %} class ='error'
{% endif %}>
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <p>Please enter your bookmark here</p>
    {{ form.url(size = 50) }}
    <p>Please enter additional description</p>
    {{ form.description(size = 50) }}
    {# <input type='text' name='url' required> #}
    <ul>
         {% for error in form.url.errors %}
            <li>{{ error }}</li>
         {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
 </form>
```

Comment: this actually works but what is my code missing from Flask aspect ?

Comment: From what I know about Flask your code doesn't seem to miss something (I may be very wrong). This tag is only added in client-side so browsers skip the built-in validations those fields have.

Comment: I'm learning flask so if I don't recieve any better answer Im gonna accept it, thanks